# Put an adorner layer behind child controls

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a canvas where I need to draw a grid, but behind child controls. I tried to create a new adroner and just add it to the canvas, but this adorner is displayed over child controls. How can I make this adorner be behind canvas' children? I don't want to draw this grid in the OnRender function of the canvas...

Clarification: grid is not a control. it is a painted grid or net on the canvas. it is created for making position elements easier.

Comment: Any reason you can't add it to the parent of the canvas (or just have a canvas nested in a canvas)?

Comment: I've thought about creation a plain control with a grid in it and just place it as a child of the canvas with the smallest z-index and the same as canvas size. But I want to find better way

Comment: Might not be a better way without overriding OnRender. I'd probably just nest two canvases and apply the adorner to the outer canvas, simple solution - ok you get a *tiny* bit messier XAML but it's a small price to pay

Comment: thanks for advice, but I think it won't work. Because we'll get the same issue. The problem is that I cant to override OnRender, because when it is called I don't have all initialized data. So I think I need to create an underlying control with a grid and put to canvas behind others... sad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a `TileBrush` as the `Canvas.Background` and set the TileBrush to an appropriate grid pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My solution was exactly the same. the easest way I found

Answer (score 1):

An `Adorner` can only ever be on top (it allways has the highest zindex). You need to look at another solution to your underlying issue

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Panel.ZIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.zindex.aspx) Property to set the order elements get displayed on the z-plane.

Comment: Are you sure that I can use zindex with Adorner? it is not a control

Comment: no, normal ZIndex does not work on Adorners (there is a way to do it, but you'll have to go through Reflection).